# Is there any published material regarding the Dragonlance campaign setting in D&D 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragonlance

I'm thinking of running a game using the Dragonlance setting (Krynn) but, at the same time, using the 5th edition system.

Has any material been published that includes information on Dragonlance in 5e?

Comment: Just FYI, I've run DL modules in 5e just converting on the fly--two minutes' puzzling through tHAC0 and ACs, then you're off to the races! Feel free to ping me in [chat] if you want to hear any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, but it’s really limited.

I believe the DMG mentions it (I don’t have mine handy to check).

The ‘splat’ books like *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* have a section on adapting backgrounds and class archetypes to Dragonlance. In that particular book, it's on page 155, ["Appendix: Class Options in Other Worlds"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/scag/class-options-in-other-worlds#Dragonlance).

Each of the hardback adventures that I have read have a few paragraphs about dropping them into DL.

Comment: *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* also mentions things about several races in different worlds/settings, including Dragonlance/Krynn. There are two or three brief mentions in Ch. 2: Elves, a subsection on dwarves in Ch. 3: Dwarves and Duergar, and a paragraph on kender and a sidebar on tinker gnomes in Ch. 5: Halflings and Gnomes.

Comment: Also, the DMG has a few scattered mentions of Dragonlance/Krynn, twice under the list of forms of government and once under the list of Known Worlds of the Material Plane. It's also mentioned twice in the description of the *orb of dragonkind*: https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/orb-of-dragonkind

Answer (score 5):

In 2022, WotC released a [Heroes of Krynn](https://dnd.wizards.com/unearthed-arcana/heroes-krynn) UA.
An official Dragonlance adventure was released later in the same year: [Shadow of the Dragon Queen](https://dndstore.wizards.com/us/product/768936/shadow-of-the-dragon-queen-book-bundle). The book also contains the Kender race, as well as the Lunar subclass for Sorcerers.